# "evilmake all" not working....please help

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc, make

I am trying to insatll idlutilis,

When I am doing : `$ evilmake`

all i get error:

```
nrutil.h:45:12: warning: ‘iminarg1’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable] 
 static int iminarg1,iminarg2; 
            ^ 
nrutil.h:45:21: warning: ‘iminarg2’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable] 
 static int iminarg1,iminarg2; 
                     ^ 
cc -c -O3 -DSDSS_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DCHECK_LEAKS -I../../include -fPIC -g -Wall nrutil.c 
ld -shared -o /home/sap/idlutils//lib/libmath.so arravsigclip.o arravsigmask.o arrmedian.o ccorrelate.o idl_mmsparse.o idl_mmeval.o memshift.o nrecipes.o nrutil.o 
arravsigclip.o: In function `vector_avsigclip': 
/home/sap/idlutils/src/math/arravsigclip.c:136: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail_local' 
arravsigmask.o: In function `vector_avsigclip_mask': 
/home/sap/idlutils/src/math/arravsigmask.c:188: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail_local' 
Makefile:34: recipe for target '/home/sap/idlutils//lib/libmath.so' failed 
make[2]: *** [/home/sap/idlutils//lib/libmath.so] Error 1 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sap/idlutils/src/math'
```

Please guys tell me where I am wrong and what to do???? I searched everything on net still since 3 days I am not able to solve please help...